# Python:Read txt file into lists

Tags: python, list

I read lots of txt file into list. This is my code

```
import glob
path = '/Users/xccxken/Desktop/NNRelease/paperVersion/*.txt'
files = glob.glob(path)
for name in files:
    with open(name) as f:
        for line in f:
            split = line.split()
            if split and all('#' not in i for i in split):
                r = split
a = []
b = []
for line in r:
    a.append(r[0])
    b.append(r[1])
```

and the output is like this

```
['water', 'water']
['shortage', 'shortage']
```

and my intended output is two lists a and b like this:

```
a = [class, company,...,XXXX]
b = [size, size,..., YYYY]
```

Every text file is as follows:

[image]

Please help me fix the code

Comment: Then you should probably create two lists and add the items to them as you go along. Do you have a question?

Comment: Then [edit] the question to give a [mcve] that *actually illustrates the problem*. SO isn't here to write this for you.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You're only processing the last line in the second loop. You clearly know that `r` contains two items, as you index it `r[0]` and `r[1]`, and yet you also iterate over it, and ignore the loop variable `line`, and then are somehow surprised when you get those two items twice each. Please think this through more carefully. Try using http://pythontutor.com/ to help you out, and follow the advice in [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
a = []
b = []
for name in files:
    with open(name) as f:
        for line in f:
            split = line.split()
            if split and all('#' not in i for i in split):
                a.append(split[0])
                b.append(split[1])

print(a) # prints ['class', 'company', 'family', 'sandwich']
print(b) # prints ['size', 'size', 'size', 'size']
```

Comment: I am sorry It's not me down voted your answer, actually I have up voted you, however, I have reputation less then 15 so I don't have right to do so now.

Comment: I appreciate your work, it helps a lot. Thank you very much for your time

Comment: @kkjoe you can accept my answer by checking the `tick` sign and that is the best way to thank anyone in stackoverflow.